# Why does my AWS command work when I run it but doesn't work in root's crontab?

Tags: cron, aws

I am trying to sync a backup folder to AWS S3, so I run:

sudo aws s3 sync --delete /var/backup/  s3://ssw-backup-bucket

It asks my ubuntu password and works fine.  But if I add it to sudo crontab-e it doesn't sync.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to add the `sudo` command itself to the command when you add it to the `sudo crontab -e`, but you might need to give the full path to `aws` like `/usr/bin/aws` for the command to run properly.  To get the full path type in `which aws`.

Comment: Thank you.  I have added the full path to cron and see if it runs tonight.

Comment: Thank you, but that did not work.  Still not synching overnight

Comment: If you just type in `sudo mail` in a terminal window it should show any messages from `cron` jobs.  Just press the corresponding number and see if it shows why the cronjob didn't run.  One of mine showed that it couldn't open a display so I had to add `export DISPLAY=":0"` towards the top of a script I wrote to run.

Comment: Thank you for the root mail tip.  It shows "fatal error: Unable to locate credentials
"  Which is strange because it works when I run it as sudo.  But I sudo'd into the root user and get the same error.  I wonder why it works for sudo but not root?